# UiCollectionViewCell random images flipping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have been looking around here for a answer with no success so now ill make a try my self.

Im trying to make a UicollectionView with different cells containing images + an animation with the cells.

I want the cells to do "random flipping" with my images (5 different images)

> UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft

in a loop with 5-6 sec delay.

the animation i have for the moment is this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.superview bringSubviewToFront:collectionView];

    [UIView transitionWithView:cell
                      duration:1.0
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                      animations:^{
                      [UICollectionViewCell commitAnimations];
                      cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];


    }
```

I know that i shouldn't use the didSelectItemAtIndexPath, but i used it just to see if the animation were right.

If you check at this video u can see what i mean, on the windows 8 phone. [Youtube video](http://youtu.be/KUOVJeOR77M?t=1m13s)

Comment: Did you get any animations to work with your test? It seems to me like it wouldn't work. If you are just testing I would recommend to do it on a static `indexPath` (0,0) and call the animation on your `viewWillLoad:`.

Comment: Yepp, my animation works when clicking on a image. @ReinierPelayo

Comment: Nevermind, I though that your code was inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` :-P. There are still a couple of holes that will need to be filled for this implementation. First of all, we don't know how your images are stored and how you are retrieving them.

Comment: Well, my CollectionView and cell are in the storyboard, same with the imageView.

my images am i getting from NSarray. And then put in this method  `[[cell collectionImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayCollectionImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];` @ReinierPelayo

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was interested on this idea so I prototyped some code. I needs to be specifically tailored to your needs but it can be a good start. Firstly, you will need to subclass your `UICollectionViewCell` in order to connect an `IBOutlet` to your imageView inside the cell. Then you can reference my code snippet to get you started.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.imageList = @[@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png", @"img4.png"];  
}

// This assumes your images are inside your Bundle.

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(updateCells:)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                  repeats:YES];

}

- (void)updateCells:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
  for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visibleIndexPaths) {
    SubclassCollectionViewCell *cell = (SubclassCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [UIView transitionWithView:cell
                      duration:1.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{
                      cell.imageView.image = [self randomImage];
                    } completion:nil];
  }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}

- (UIImage *)randomImage
{
  NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % [self.imageList count];
  return [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageList objectAtIndex:randomNumber]];
}
```

### Update:

If you want only one cell at a time to randomly flip, you will need to take out the `for` loop in the `updateCells` method. Instead, try this:

```
- (void)updateCells:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
  NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [visibleIndexPaths count];
  NSindexPath *randomIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:randomIndex inSection:0];

  SubclassCollectionViewCell *cell = (SubclassCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  [UIView transitionWithView:cell
                    duration:1.0f
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                  animations:^{
                    cell.imageView.image = [self randomImage];
                  } 
                  completion:nil
  ];
}
```

Comment: Got it to work for one cell!! Will try to get 8 cells in the view to animate randomly now. Do u think i will need 8 different cells in the storyboard, or would it be easier to implement it in the code? @Reinier Pelayo

Comment: You can do it through code by upping the `numberOfItemsInSection:` or using your data source "count". The only problem I see now is that all cells will flip at the same time. If that is not what you want, you will need to add some random delay to the `updateCells:`. It would be nice if the `transitionWithView:` had some delay param built in. ;-)

Comment: Yeah iv'e been trying that. `- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.imageList.count;
}`and also been playing around with `(arc4random() % 5) +15`. In time interval but with bad result. @Reinier Pelayo

Answer (score 0):

Edited post:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

int interval = 5+(rand() % 6);


int section = 0;
int row = (arc4random() % self.cellList.count);


NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];


CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCells:)
                               userInfo:cell
                                repeats:NO];

    NSLog(@"seconds: %d", interval);
    NSLog(@"row: %d", row);
    }

- (void)updateCells:(NSTimer *)timer{
CollectionCell* cell = [timer userInfo];
[UIView transitionWithView:cell
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    cell.collectionImageView.image = [self randomImage];
                } completion:nil];



int interval = 5+(rand() % 5);

NSLog(@"speed: %d", interval);

int section = 0;
int row = (arc4random() % self.cellList.count);

NSLog(@"row: %d", row);

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
CollectionCell *newCell = (CollectionCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCells:)
                               userInfo:newCell
                                repeats:NO];}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.cellList.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


{
    CGRect frame = self.collectionView.frame;
    [collectionView setFrame:frame];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [collectionView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self cellTitleAndBackground:cell indexPath:indexPath];


    return cell;

}



- (void)cellTitleAndBackground:(CollectionCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Get title
    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", self.cellList[indexPath.row]];

    // Create title background
    UILabel *titleBackground = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 70, 70, 30)];
    titleBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleBackground.alpha = 0.6f;
    titleBackground.tag = 70;
    [self removeReusedLabel:cell tag:70];
    [cell addSubview:titleBackground];


    // Create titleLabel
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 70, 70, 30)];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    titleLabel.text = name;
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.tag = 72;
    [self removeReusedLabel:cell tag:72];
    [cell addSubview:titleLabel];
}

-(void)removeReusedLabel:(CollectionCell *)cell tag:(int)tag {
    UILabel *foundLabelBackground = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:tag];
    if (foundLabelBackground) [foundLabelBackground removeFromSuperview];
}



- (UIImage *)randomImage
{
    // Random image for cells
    NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % [self.imageList count];
    return [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageList objectAtIndex:randomNumber]];
}
```

Comment: I can see how multiple cells are flipping at the same time. First, you are calling the `updateCells` method on all visible cells from the beginning and making them flip, "all" is key here, now, since you are on the `viewDidLoad` method and the view has not "appeared" yet, you may only see some of them flipping. Also, you are spanning new `NSTimer` objects on that same method, not efficient. Instead, try modifying the same timer passed as a method argument.

Comment: I got it to kinda work, the cells is animating one at a time, randomly. But now when i got 8 cells and scrolling down, the pictures is changing with the cell next to it. Been trying to fix it with setFrameand setNeedsDisplay but without success. edited my answer so u can see how i made it now. @ReinierPelayo